# Sorting Through Multidimensional Dataset Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a bar graph using d3 with a dataset containing sets of 3 values. The first value is the bar height, the second is the bar width, and the third is the opacity. My goal now is to be able to sort by height, width, then opacity in a cycle using a click. However, I feel like I'm getting seemingly random results after the first click.

I'm supposed to use the modulus operation so I set var s = -1 outside the click function and then s = (s+1)%3. Inside the sort function, I have return `d3.ascending(a[s],b[s]);`.

This is my code for the click and sort.

```
var s = -1;
svg.on("click", function() {
    s = (s + 1)
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(a[s], b[s]);
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return xScale(i);
        })
});
```

I expected the sort by height, width, then opacity. I get height on the first click but the next clicks are seemingly random sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this seemingly innocuous data binding:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)// <----- here
    .sort(function(a, b) {
    //etc...
```

The issue is that you're appending the data to previously sorted rectangles **by their indices**. This is messing with the sort.

Here is a simple explanation. Suppose you have 5 elements (in upper case), corresponding to the data array `[d, a, e, c, b]` (in lower case), which you want to sort alphabetically:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| D(d) | A(a) | E(e) | C(c) | B(b) | 
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

After sorting, you have:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| A(a) | B(b) | C(c) | D(d) | E(e) | 
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

When you re-bind the data (remember, the same `[d, a, e, c, b]` array, in that order) to the **already sorted** elements, you have:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| A(d) | B(a) | C(e) | D(c) | E(b) | 
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

If you sort this **by the data** (which is what `selection.sort()` does), you'll have:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| B(a) | E(b) | D(c) | A(d) | C(e) | 
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

And that's why it seems *random*, as you said.

There are two solutions:

**Solution 1: drop the data binding**

The simplest one is just dropping the data binding, since the rectangles already have data. Here is an example with 3 rectangles, such as each one has either the biggest height, width or opacity:

```js
var data = [
  [45, 90, 0.5],
  [95, 10, 0.2],
  [15, 40, 0.9]
];

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain([0, 1, 2])
  .range([0, 100, 200]);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var span = d3.select("span")

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", d => d[1])
  .attr("height", d => d[0])
  .style("opacity", d => d[2])
  .attr("x", (_, i) => xScale(i));

var s = -1;
svg.on("click", function() {
  s = (s + 1);
  span.html(["height", "width", "opacity"][s % 3]);
  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return d3.ascending(a[s % 3], b[s % 3]);
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>Sort by: <span></span></p>
<svg></svg>
```

**Solution 2: use a key function**

The second solution is using a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data), so you don't bind the data by their indices, but according to an unique identification to each rectangle instead.

In my dummy data each height value is unique, so I just do:

```
.data(dataset, d=>d[0])
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [
  [45, 90, 0.5],
  [95, 10, 0.2],
  [15, 40, 0.9]
];

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain([0, 1, 2])
  .range([0, 100, 200]);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var span = d3.select("span")

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", d => d[1])
  .attr("height", d => d[0])
  .style("opacity", d => d[2])
  .attr("x", (_, i) => xScale(i));

var s = -1;
svg.on("click", function() {
  s = (s + 1);
  span.html(["height", "width", "opacity"][s % 3]);
  svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(data, d=>d[0])
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return d3.ascending(a[s % 3], b[s % 3]);
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>Sort by: <span></span></p>
<svg></svg>
```